# Creating a function using DrRacket that takes two lists and outputs it as a fraction

Tags: racket

Write a function that takes two lists of numbers, numerators and denominators, and returns a list of fractions produced by dividing numerators by denominators. If one list is shorter than the other, assume that the corresponding numbers are all 1s. Don't worry about zeros in the denominators (it's ok if your function breaks when dividing by zero).

Input: (list 1 2 3) (list 1 3 5)

Output: (list 1/1 2/3 3/5)

Comment: Is the result supposed to be a list of strings or numbers?

Comment: (the printer will show `(/ 1 1)` or any other exact number with a denominator of 1 as just the numerator since it's an integer value)

Comment: If it's numbers, as long as the lists are the same size, `(map / numerators denominators)` works. Accounting for different lengths is where it gets interesting.

Comment: its suppose to output a list of numbers and it should print out like (list 2/3 3/4 4/5) for example. If one of the lists is shorter than the other it should use a 1 instead.

Comment: Write down all the possible input cases (there are four) and solve one at a time. If you get stuck on one case, try a different one. Don't worry about writing it in Racket; describe the solution in a human language first.

Comment: If you're stuck on the differing lengths, note that if the lists are not of the same length, recursion will reach an empty list on one before the other. (And those cases are simple with `map`.)

Comment: @molbdnilo thats the exact part im stuck on rn lol I'm trying to add the 1s to the end of the list depending on the length difference but do not know exactly how. I know I could just append a 1 to a list but idk how to add multiple.

Comment: Ok, the big thing that you're missing is that you don't need to worry about lengths at all - all you need to worry about is the structure of the input lists. If you had only a list of numerators or only a list of denominators, `(1 2 3)` say, how could you get `(1/1 1/2 1/3)` or `(1/1 2/1 3/1)`? Once you know that (hint: `map`), think of my previous comment about the recursion for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by recursion:

```
(define (r-map func l1 l2 (default-l1 1) (default-l2 1) (acc '()))
  (cond ((and (null? l1) (null? l2)) (reverse acc))
        ((null? l1) (r-map func '() (cdr l2) default-l1 default-l2 (cons (func default-l1 (car l2)) acc)))
        ((null? l2) (r-map func (cdr l1) '() default-l1 default-l2 (cons (func (car l1) default-l2) acc)))
        (else (r-map func (cdr l1) (cdr l2) default-l1 default-l2 (cons (func (car l1) (car l2)) acc)))))
```

The nice thing with this function is that you can change the default value for each list independently from each other.

Test it:

```
(define a '(1 2 3))
(define b '(4 5 6))
(define c '(10 20))
(define d '(40 50 60 70))

;; run all combinations of the four:
(let ((lists (list a b c d)))
  (for*/list [(x lists)
              (y lists)]
    (list `(r-map ,x ,y ,default-l1 ,default-l2) '=> (r-map / x y))))
```

It returns:

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 6.11 [3m].
Language: racket, with debugging; memory limit: 128 MB.
'(((r-map (1 2 3) (1 2 3) 1 1) => (1 1 1))
  ((r-map (1 2 3) (4 5 6) 1 1) => (1/4 2/5 1/2))
  ((r-map (1 2 3) (10 20) 1 1) => (1/10 1/10 3))
  ((r-map (1 2 3) (40 50 60 70) 1 1) => (1/40 1/25 1/20 1/70))
  ((r-map (4 5 6) (1 2 3) 1 1) => (4 2 1/2 2))
  ((r-map (4 5 6) (4 5 6) 1 1) => (1 1 1))
  ((r-map (4 5 6) (10 20) 1 1) => (2/5 1/4 6))
  ((r-map (4 5 6) (40 50 60 70) 1 1) => (1/10 1/10 1/10 1/70))
  ((r-map (10 20) (1 2 3) 1 1) => (10 10 1/3))
  ((r-map (10 20) (4 5 6) 1 1) => (2 1/2 4 1/6))
  ((r-map (10 20) (10 20) 1 1) => (1 1))
  ((r-map (10 20) (40 50 60 70) 1 1) => (1/4 2/5 1/60 1/70))
  ((r-map (40 50 60 70) (1 2 3) 1 1) => (40 25 20 70))
  ((r-map (40 50 60 70) (4 5 6) 1 1) => (10 10 10 70))
  ((r-map (40 50 60 70) (10 20) 1 1) => (4 2 1/2 60 70))
  ((r-map (40 50 60 70) (40 50 60 70) 1 1) => (1 1 1 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's do this a bit more straightforwardly.

There are two simple cases:

- Both lists are empty; the result is `'()`
- Neither list is empty; `cons` the fraction of the `car`s onto the result of recursing.

Short-circuiting out the tricky cases:

```
(define (fractions ns ds)
  (cond [(and (null? ns) (null? ds)) '()]
        [(null? ns) 'only-denominators]
        [(null? ds) 'only-numerators]
        [else (cons (/ (car ns) (car ds)) (fractions (cdr ns) (cdr ds)))]))
```

Test:

```
> (fractions '() '())
'()
> (fractions '(1 2) '(4 5))
'(1/4 2/5)
> (fractions '(1 2 3) '(4 5))
'(1/4 2/5 . only-numerators)
> (fractions '(1 2) '(4 5 6))
'(1/4 2/5 . only-denominators)
```

If there are only numerators, the results are the same as those numerators, since `x/1` is the same as `x`:

```
...
[(null? ds) ns]
...
```

And if there are only denominators, you divide `1` with each element.
This is easy with `map`:

```
...
[(null? ns) (map (lambda (d) (/ 1 d)) ds)]
...
```

In full:

```
(define (fractions ns ds)
  (cond [(and (null? ns) (null? ds)) '()]
        [(null? ns) (map (lambda (d) (/ 1 d)) ds)]
        [(null? ds) ns]
        [else (cons (/ (car ns) (car ds)) (fractions (cdr ns) (cdr ds)))]))
```

Test:

```
> (fractions '() '(4 5 6))
'(1/4 1/5 1/6)
> (fractions '(1 2 3) '())
'(1 2 3)
> (fractions '(1 2 3) '(4 5))
'(1/4 2/5 3)
> (fractions '(1 2) '(4 5 6))
'(1/4 2/5 1/6)
```